# Redirect all JPEG URL to single JPEG ing NGINX

Tags: redirect, nginx

There are two scenario that I'm trying to achieve.

Scenario A : If client request URL that contains .jpeg or .jpg file, redirect the user to a single .jpg file that are on the server in this case myimage.jpg

Scenario B : If client request URL that contains /abc/ directory, redirect the user to other domain through proxy while keeping the URL in tact.

Below is the content of my nginx.conf

```
http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        #Scenario A
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg){
           rewrite ^$ /myimage.jpg break;
        }

        #Scenario B
        location ^~ /abc/ {
            proxy_pass http://cd.mycontent.com.my;
            proxy_redirect localhost http://cd.mycontent.com.my;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }
    }
......
```

Most of it I referred to [Nginx redirect to a single file](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23141/nginx-redirect-to-php-file-if-image-does-not-exist-on-file-server) The config does not contain error in /var/log/nginx/error.log but it does not perform as intended to.

---

**UPDATE for Scenario A :**

I've added the root directive but it still does not rewrite the URL. I managed to achieve this in Apache but not in Nginx. In Apache, I only create htaccess file with content as follows :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Check URL if contain .jpeg or .jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (\.jpeg|\.jpg)$
RewriteRule (.*)  myimage.jpg [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

With this htaccess, I can rewrite any URL request with .jpeg|.jpg and user will be shown the image of myimage.jpg instead of whatever jpeg|jpg image they requested with their URL. I've tried using htaccess to nginx converter [here](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your configuration. You do not appear to have a `root` directive defined, and the rewrite will loop. Also, not sure about using an absolute redirect with the `last` modifier.

```
root /path/to/document/root;

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg) {
    rewrite ^ /myimage.jpg break;
}
```

Note that the regex will match URIs with an embedded `.jpg` string. If you only want to match URIs that end with `.jpg`, append a `$`.

The `break` will prevent a redirect loop by processing the URI within the same location block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.